# MySQL Workbench 6.1 syntax errors in every statement

Tags: mysql-workbench

If I open up MySQL Workbench 6.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, and try to execute even a simple statement like

`UPDATE articles SET published = 1;`

It throws a syntax error when using the explain option:

> Error executing explain
>   ("You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE articles SET published = 1' at line 1", 1064)

I know there is no syntax error because I can copy and paste that exact statement into MySQL command line and it works.

Select statements are fine, but not updates or inserts. I have no idea what's wrong and it's incredibly frustrating.

Comment: missing `WHERE` statement?

Comment: WHERE is not required on update. And again, I can run that statement in command line and it works just fine.

Comment: It is just that I have seen systems with security rules, that would throw an error like that. You can try, just for fun `WHERE 1`.

Comment: Same syntax error. Even made sure that Workbench is not in safe mode that prevents updates/inserts from executing without a WHERE key.

Comment: can you share more code?

Comment: That very much sounds like a bug to me. Can you try the latest version instead (6.2.3)?